# C# code effectiveness - calling a property tens of times

Tags: c#, .net

**IDE:** Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

**Language:** C# / .NET 4.5

**Situation:** Suppose I defined a class and I'm calling its properties tens of times, further let's suppose the class operates over one input given to the constructor and therefore it makes all operations except the first one redundant, because we already managed to calculate the return value the first time we called it.

**Example of such property:**

```
// let's call it a Month, because it extracts a month code from a string
private int Month
{
    // there is only a getter
    get
    {
        // here's my current strategy
        // in the beginning of the class I set fMonth to -1
        // it can only have possitive numbers, so if already set, I return it
        if (fMonth > -1)
            return fMonth;

        // and here's the part I don't want to repeat
        return fMonth =
            Convert.ToInt32(SomeNumberString.Substring(2, 2));
     }
}
```

**Question:** Is this the right strategy for not repeating the executive code?

Comment: You've got your hypothesis, why not test it in the debugger and form a conclusion?

Comment: @MickyD Thank you for the comment. I am not really familiar with VS yet. And I am unsure how to form any conclusion from the debugger :(

Comment: You seem to be trying to reinvent [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) (although here, with a trivial computation, it's not necessarily worth doing anything)

Comment: why not encapsulate a field `month` and set its value whenever you set `SomeNumberString`? There could be many different approach depending on the problem and  I'm not sure how you measure `effectiveness` because AFAIK it either works or not. Also, you can measure your algorithm using `Big-O` notation but that's a different story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with using a private backing field `fmonth` for the property. You can further optimize this by moving the conversion code to an explicit set method. This removes the `if` check from every get access.

```
ctor(string someNumberString) {
    SetMonth(someNumberString);
}

private int Month { get { return fmonth; } }
// -1 indicates that SetMonth() has never been called
private int fmonth = -1;

public void SetMonth(string someNumberString) {
    fmonth = Convert.ToInt32(someNumberString.Substring(2, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the value for `someNumberString` is given to you in the constructor, you can use a readonly property.

```
ctor(string someNumberString)
{
    Month = Convert.ToInt32(someNumberString.Substring(2, 2));
}

public Month { get; }
```